# How would I merge 2 git repos with conflicting commits?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo on github which is a fork of another repository, my fork has recently been unmaintained but many files are conflicting.

How would I use something like git cherry-pick to make the fork up to date with the main repo?

Comment: What did you try and where was the problem? You say *many files are conflicting*; how do you know that?

Comment: I tried using github gui to fetch upstream, it didnt work.

Comment: *Didn't work* is not a problem description. Surely, there was some indication of a problem. Let us know what it was.

Comment: see the only answer here.....

Comment: also it may not be a problem description, but you can tell what I mean by your previous comment :^)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your end goal.

If the fork has current work you want to keep,  but is behind the upstream (original repository it has forked), I would rebase my working branch (assuming it is not `main`) on top of upstream/main.

I would resolve conflicts during the rebase.
This is safer than cherry-picking.

```sh
cd /path/to/repo
git remote add upstream https://github.com/original/repository
git fetch upstream
git switch myBranch
# or, if you were working from main directly
git switch -c myBranch main
git rebase upstream/main
```

(replace `main` by `master` if this was an old repository with the [previous default branch naming convention](https://github.com/github/renaming))

Comment: I will try this after I wake up, thanks for the help!